# Azure data factory webhook activity fails after 1 min

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-data-factory

I am using python flask server. Azure data factory calls through webhook activity. The calls were successful if they run within a min but fails if i have long running processes. I understand we need to implement a polling methodology so that the flask server sends status messages back to the client. I am lost as to how this polling methodology works between flask and data factory.

Comment: How long will the process take? did you set the timeout property with more time in webhook active?

Comment: the process takes about 10 min. it has nothing to do with timeout. data factory is failing the webhook activity if it passes 1 min and if there is no response from the server.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply